# Hot Encoding in production

Tags: machine-learning, spark-mllib

I am using spark to perform random forest classification in a data frame with following structure

```
amount marital gender sector
10000  married male   agri
12421  single  male   agri
14000  single  female business
20000  marital female business
```

I am trying to predict the sector, using other variables. As you can see marital and gender both are categorical, spark can only handle numeric data thus these have to hot encoded

**Expected structure**

```
amount marital_married marital_single gender_male gender_female sector
10000  1               0              1           0             agri
12421  0               1              1           0             agri
14000  0               1              0           1             business
20000  1               0              0           1             business
```

**Questions:**

```
How predicted model handle new class in marital, does the model always expect the same data format that is a wide dataset which is hot encoded for every possible combination for every categorical column?

How does the model predict the sector, as a number(1) or as string (Agri)?
```

Basically i am trying to understand how models which use hot-encoding work and how they are used in production grade settings! Hope I was clear in my questions

Comment: What does "churn the sector" mean?

Comment: I meant predict, does it return "Agri" or "1"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using a [RandomForestClassifier](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#random-forest-classifier) from the new Spark ML library (as opposed to MLlib which will be gradually phased out). For that you need to convert your data into a Spark dataframe:

```
dataset = spark.createDataFrame([
...     (1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0)),
...     (0.0, Vectors.sparse(1, [], []))], ["label", "features"])
```

Once the data is loaded into the dataframe, you want to make sure that it contains numeric types (as opposed to strings) in order to run classification.
In the case of categorical data, an alternative to one hot encoding (which can generate a lot of columns) is to use a [StringIndexer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer):

```
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="gender", outputCol="genderInd")
dataset = indexer.fit(dataset).transform(dataset)
```

this will encode your data into a column of label indices.  If you have multiple features, you would need to group them using [VectorAssembler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler) into a single features vector:

```
assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=["amount", "maritalInd","genderInd"],
    outputCol="features")
```

Once that is done, you are ready to instantiate Random Forest Classifier and fit the model:

```
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(numTrees=100, maxDepth=6, labelCol="sectorInd", featuresCol="features", seed=0)
model = rfc.fit(trainingData)
```

For more information, have a look at the [classification example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/ml/random_forest_classifier_example.py) and [API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html).